# Django migrations.AlterField choices's orders are being altered. Can I delete this?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

Unfortunately, I'm running into some problems migrating Django migrations files since I have way too many models for, let's say, this extremely specific database; therefore, I have 6 migrations files. I have this many for the simple reason of "there are too many models." I'm trying to deduce the reason for being unable to migrate, and I believe it to be 1) (the pointer given to me) stack overflow and 2) memory.

This is the code in the migrations file that I want to delete:

```
operations = [
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='pnote1',
        name='status',
        field=models.CharField(choices=[('5', 'test5'), ('4', 'test4'), ('3', 'test3'), ('6', 'test6'), ('1', 'test1'), ('2', 'test2')], default='1', max_length=1),
    ),
```

There are 100's of these AlterFields. I'm wondering if I can delete them without harming the database; it just seemed redundant to have these AlterFields, even though nothing was altered. The models (inherited from an abstract model) have this as:

```
option = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE, default='1')
```

The order of the choices I originally had were 1-6, not this jumble. And in each migration file, the number of migrations.AlterField just keep increasing for some odd reason. So again, can I delete this without harming the database?

Edit: This is when I was migrating, not making migrations.

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00001528 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\contextlib.py", line 130 in __exit__
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 318 in render_multiple
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 191 in _reload
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 158 in reload_model
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 97 in add_model
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\models.py", line 86 in state_forwards
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 114 in apply
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 245 in apply_migration
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147 in _migrate_all_forwards
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117 in migrate
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234 in handle
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83 in wrapped
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364 in execute
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323 in run_from_argv
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375 in execute
  File "C:\Users\test\test\testvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381 in execute_from_command_line
  File "manage.py", line 17 in main
  File "manage.py", line 21 in <module>
```

Edit2:

```
class Stick1(models.Model):
  TYPE = {
    ('1', 'test1'),
    ('2', 'test2'),
    ('3', 'test3'),
    ('4', 'test4'),
    ('5', 'test5'),
    ('6', 'test6'),
  }
  option = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE, default='1')
```

Comment: don't delete migrations files - show the error you're getting.  Full traceback please

Comment: @HenryM Err not exactly deleting the migration files themselves as there are other models being created. I'm simply deleting those lines. Here's the first error: Fatal python error cannot recover from stack overflow.

Comment: As I said, please show full traceback.  I would always say don't delete any parts of the migrations files unless you really know what you're doing

Comment: Second Error: Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from MemoryErrors while normalizing exceptions.

Comment: Yikes ok. Will.... try to reproduce the error. It also took an extremely long time to even have the errors show up... if that helps at all.

Comment: Please show the model that this AlterField refers to.

Comment: (In particular, show *exactly* how `TYPE` is defined.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Edited